# App crashes after sending mail using SMTP

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my iPhone app, i used SMTP for sending email.all works perfectly while sending mail. But sometimes after the mail has been sent, the app suddenly crashes with the following error message

```
 <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myid.smtpsample[0x2630]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
��May  6 17:07:21 Device-3 ReportCrash[13041] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
```

This is My Code:

```
-(void) sendEmail
{
    NSData *imagedata=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2f);

    SKPSMTPMessage *Message = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    Message.fromEmail = @"my email";
    Message.toEmail = receiverEmailString;
    Message.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
    Message.requiresAuth = YES;
    Message.login = @"my email";
    Message.pass = @"my password";
    Message.subject = @"Details";
    Message.wantsSecure = YES; 
    Message.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,@"Message Body",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

    NSDictionary *vcfPart= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image/jpeg;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"MyPhoto.jpg\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                             @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"MyPhoto.jpg\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[imagedata encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

    Message.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];
    [Message send];

}


- (void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"delegate - error(%d): %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message{

    NSLog(@"delegate - message sent");


}
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a bit late to answer this. But might help someone else. So here goes.

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it. The only thing that I had to do was add a strong reference to the SKPSMTPMessage object, and refer it when sending the email. Works like a charm. (oh and also I left `message = nil;` in tact and it didn't cause any problems for me.)

```
     @interface MyViewController ()    
     @property (nonatomic, strong) SKPSMTPMessage *Message;
     @end

    -(void) sendEmail
    {
        _Message = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
        _Message.fromEmail = @"my email";
        _Message.toEmail = receiverEmailString;
        ...
        [_Message send];

    }


    - (void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error{
        message = nil;
        NSLog(@"delegate - error(%d): %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    - (void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message{    
        message = nil;
        NSLog(@"delegate - message sent"); 
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You create Message in a method, give it self as a delegate (implying its going to message you when it's finished), but just after the send message, Message is released by ARC when you leave the method. So, create a Message ivar, and only nil it after it tells you it succeeded or failed (and do that in a block dispatched to the main thread, it's risky to nil or release objects directly in delegate callbacks).

PS: also, please use lowercase for class instances and uppercase first letter for class objects.

Comment: Since you have not given the sample code, I had to up vote the same solution with code.

Comment: @Thiru, I understand. Its just so much easier to copy and paste a solution, and never have to think about what that code does, or why. Silly me - I'm just such an old fashioned developer.